# bash scripting one line shortcut for if test

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a shortcut (ie all on one line) for doing the following?

```
if [ -z "$PASSWORD" ] ; then
    echo "PASSWORD envvar required. Exiting..."
    exit 1
fi
```

I'm thinking along the lines of the following. Or maybe there's an even shorter way.

```
[ -z "$PASSWORD" ] && ...
```

That is, how do put the echo then exit after the **&&**

Comment: `: ${PASSWORD:?}`

Comment: Ummm... can you give a bit more explanation? It looks useful but I don't know how it would apply here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
[ -z "$PASSWORD" ] && { echo "PASSWORD envvar required. Exiting..."; exit 1; }
```

Note the extra `;` at the end of the line before the `}`, this is necessary and you cannot leave it out.

It's called [a command group.](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/grouping_plain)

Answer (score -4):

```
[[ -z "$PASSWORD" ]] && echo "PASSWORD envvar required. Exiting." && exit 1
```

Your single brackets will work fine.  [Consider learning to use the doubles, though.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306111/what-is-the-difference-between-the-bash-operators-vs-vs-vs)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in this case the `exit 1` will always be executed, whether the test is true or not

Comment: It will not.  It will execute only if the previous command successfully executes.  Since it will only execute if the first is true, then `exit` only hits if the first is true as well.

Comment: The problem is that this code will not exit if the `echo` fails for any reason.

Comment: Yeah, and under what circumstances would echo fail?  All it does is shoves text to stdout.

Comment: `echo` can fail if stdout is full, for example.

Comment: He's checking the existence of a password.  After doing this for a decade and a half, I have yet to see echo fail.

Comment: `echo hi > /dev/full || echo "Surprise, echo failed"`

Comment: Then don't send it to `/dev/full`, surprise don't do stupid things if you don't want stupid results.

Comment: `/dev/null` simple returns the code for 'no space left on device'.  He's sending a few bytes to screen.

Comment: What if your script runs in a context where stdout is redirected to a log file residing on a file system that's out of space? (Not a hypothetical example, I've seen this happen.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182237/discussion-between-utahjarhead-and-melpomene).